# raster: download worldclim 5 minutes altitude and calculate earth surface area

Tags: r, r-raster

I've like to download worldclim 5 minutes altitude using getData() function and calculate surface area. For this a make:

```
library(raster)

#Download worldclim 5 minutes altitude for whole world 

elevation_world <- getData('worldclim', var='alt', res=5, lon=180, lat=85)

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In utils::unzip(zipfile, exdir = dirname(zipfile)) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
2: In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/fores/Documents/wc5/alt.hdr': No such file or directory

elevation_world <- getData('worldclim', var='alt', res=5, lon=-180, lat=-85)

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In utils::unzip(zipfile, exdir = dirname(zipfile)) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
2: In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/fores/Documents/wc5/alt.hdr': No such file or directory
```

Doesn't work with my lat/long choises, why?

Second, I've like too with elevation_world object calculate earth surface area:

```
grids <- as(elevation_world, "SpatialGridDataFrame")
proj4string(grids) <- CRS(wgs.84)
areaSpatialGrid(grids)
```

and I expected as output in km2 something like:

```
[1]510072000
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
library(raster)
r <- getData('worldclim', var='alt', res=5)
a <- area(r)
b <- mask(a, r)
cellStats(b, sum)
#[1] 137881247
```

But note that this excludes Antarctica. Instead you could do

As for your first question: these arguments do not apply.